# sparkR-2.0.0 gives "Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :..."

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

When I try to use sparkR in Rstudio, I met some problems.

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
library(rJava)
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))
fa<- faithful
df <- as.DataFrame(fa)
```

And got the ERROR below:
    sc <- sparkR.session(master="spark://spark01.cmua.dom:7077", appName="sparkR", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g"))

df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)

get error below:

```
 Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :           
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedSt
```

Comment: It would be better if you can include the text of the stack trace, rather than a link to an external image. This allows people who are searching for the same error to find your question (and hopefully it's answers).

Comment: Have you added Java Home while setting environment?
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_101') # for 64-bit version

Comment: I am not sure whether it is the java's problem I think.
Actually, yesterday, I add 
     "spark.sql.warehouse.dir = "my_hadoop_home/bin""
a few more codes in my sparkConfig, and then there is no error.